# Php: перебор вариантов заполнения массива единицами

Tags: php, алгоритм

Здравствуйте! Подскажите, пожалуйста, возможный алгоритм решения задачи:
одномерный массив может быть заполнен только единицами и нулями (незаполненных элементов быть не может). Необходимо получить все возможные варианты заполнения этого массива.

Comment: Задача решилась, вопрос можно закрывать.

Comment: Если задача решена самостоятельно, то правилом хорошего тона будет выложить свой ответ сюда.

Comment: Да, у меня решение совпало с ответом.

Answer (score 4, accepted):

вот такой есть выход конкретно для 0/1:

```
<?php
function variants($length) {
  $max=bindec(str_pad("",$length,"1"));  
  for ($i=0;$i<=$max;$i++) {
        $variant=str_split(str_pad(decbin($i),$length,"0"));            
        print_r($variant);
  }
}

variants(5);
```